# Ubuntu apt-get update - signatures couldn't be verified error

Tags: ubuntu

I am trying to run `apt-get update` on a Ubuntu 15.04 install but I am getting the following error...

`W: GPG error: http://dl.yarnpkg.com stable InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 46C2130DFD2497F5`

I tried to get the key with `sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 46C2130DFD2497F5` but that gives me the following error...

```
gpg: requesting key FD2497F5 from hkp server keyserver.ubuntu.com
gpgkeys: key 46C2130DFD2497F5 can't be retrieved
gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found.
gpg: Total number processed: 0
```

I am behind a company proxy and have added my proxy settings but still continue to get the error.

```
HTTP_PROXY="http://MY_PROXY:8080/"
http_proxy="http://MY_PROXY:8080/"
HTTPS_PROXY="https://MY_PROXY:8080/"
https_proxy="https://MY_PROXY:8080/"
ftp_proxy="ftp://MY_PROXY:8080/"
socks_proxy="socks://MY_PROXY:8080/"
```

Can anyone give me some advice?

Thanks

Comment: `no valid OpenPGP data found.` provied openPGp data

Comment: @Felix Would you mind expanding your comment a little? How would I go about providing OpenPGP data?

Answer (score 0):

In my particular case this was being caused by an updated company firewall config. Once it was properly configured this now works.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that uses http via curl instead of trying to proxy apt-key or gpg:

```
curl -sSL \
'http://keyserver.ubuntu.com/pks/lookup?op=get&search=0x46C2130DFD2497F5' \
| sudo apt-key add
```

(do not forget the leading `0x` before the key)